# Would anybody hel me with this error: std_logic_vector can not have such operands with returned type std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

```
    when validar =>
                    if( mov = "00" and std_logic_vector(pos_y) = "00") then
                        estado_siguiente <= detectar_mov;
                    else if(mov = "01" and std_logic_vector(pos_y) = "11") then
                        estado_siguiente <= detectar_mov;
                    else if(mov = "10" and std_logic_vector(pos_x) = "00") then
                        estado_siguiente <= detectar_mov;
                    else if(mov = "11" and std_logic_vector(pos_x) = "11") then
                        estado_siguiente <= detectar_mov;
                    else estado_siguiente <= actualizar_pos;
                    end if;
```

Both mov and pos_y/pos_x are unsigned. This is part of a fsm

Comment: Without the whole code in context, there is little that can be said. Post the whole code.

Comment: Or a [mcve] that reproduces the error.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to check your usage of `if` and `else if`. It looks like you want to use `elsif` instead. In the example above you're opening several nested `if` clauses after each `else` (missing their corresponding `end if` clauses) which is certainly not intended.